# iOS: 221 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I updated to the newest Xcode version and my App was building fine so far. But now it doesn’t. I tried two days everything I found, but no way.

The error is:

```
221 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

and then

```
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

My ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8 

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.10.2
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

I also tried

```
ionic cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```

Setting binaryMode on/off in Xcode
Complete reinstall ionic/cordova
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console is not necessary anymore
It has worked with all the plugins before, so I think that the plugins can’t be the problem.

Can anybody please give me a hint?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix?

Answer (score -2):

Suggestion:
Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Select the button highlighted in the image attached -> Delete the DerivedData folder.

Command + Option + Shift + K

Command + Shift + K

And compile again.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

changing 'No Common Blocks' in build settings ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) from Yes to No will fix the problem.